# Toggle show/hide div with button for multiple result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, show-hide

i am developing a classroom students attendance site, what i am doing and what i expected my php coding, its working fine... when update attendance each student just click over each student thumbnails from students list page, its working...

my question is i had added a `add description` button for each students over thumbnails, its invisible, when user hover mouse over student thumbnails only show this button, then i had added a toggle show/hide div with button, when user click this visible button my small form div will display...

this is i used for toggle show/hide div with button...

**HTML**

```
<div id='content'>form content here</div>
<input type='button' id='hideshow' value='add description'>
```

**Jquery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#content').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

its working when click add description button, but my problem is if i have more than 2 or above students my list when i click this button all students form content div display now, i need only one student div display, i mean which student above button we click, only that display... i think this problem because of used unique id, how to fix it.? any idea.???

**EDIT**
this is my php generated students list display

```
<?php if ($students) { ?>
        <?php foreach ($students as $student) { ?>    
        <div class="student">
        <div class="thumb">
        <div class="content" style="display:none;">
            DIV CONTENT HERE
        </div>
        <input type='button' id='hideshow' value='add description'>    
        <img class="img" src="<?php echo $student['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $student['name']; ?>" />
        </div>    
        <div class="name"><?php echo $student['name']; ?><?php echo $student['student_id']; ?></div> 
        </div>
       <?php } else { ?>
    <div class="empty"><?php echo $text_empty; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

this is the screenshot what i got now...
[image]

this is what i really looking for
[image]

thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your problem. Try using `prev()` to get the previous sibling and use `class="content"` not `id` as there are multiple.

Also [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated, prefer [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) since `.live()` was removed in v1.9.

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#hideshow').on('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery(this).prev('.content').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='content'>form content here</div>
<input type='button' id='hideshow' value='add description'>
```

### Update

Now that you include your PHP I understand the problem. The issue is that you're using an `id` for `hideshow`, `id`s are supposed to be unique and I believe jQuery actually stops checking if there are more than one. Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class='content'>form content here</div>
<input type='button' class='hideshow' value='add description'>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.hideshow').on('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery(this).prev('.content').toggle();
    });
});
```

So the differences to my original answer is that it's not using the class `.hideshow`, not an `id`, and we're simply calling `.toggle()` to show/hide instead of using the CSS class `.show`.

Comment: its not working still... i had updated my question with php generated students list... can you look it.?

Answer (score 0):

Try to loop for multiple students like

```
foreach($total_stndts as $row)
{
    echo "<div class='content_<?php echo $row['stdnt_id'];?>'>form content here</div>";
    echo "<input type='button' id='<?php echo $row['stdnt_id'];?>' value='add description'>";   
}
```

then in your jquery try to fire like

```
$("input[type='button']").live('click',function(){
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#content_'+id).toggle('show');  
})
```